# Invoking a method from constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am invoking a method in my constructor like below.Is this the right way to do to set properties based on some validations.Please suggest.

```
    public class Asset
    {
      public Asset(string id)
      {
        SetStorageId(id);
      }

      public string AssetId { get; set; }

      public string UtilId { get; set; }

      public string MappingId { get; set; }

      public bool IsActive { get; set; }

      private void SetStorageId(string id)
      {
          if (Regex.Match(id, "^[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*$").Success)
          {
              AssetId = id;
          }
          else
          {
            UtilId = id;
          }
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply try this

```
public class Asset
{
    private string id;


    public string AssetId { get; set; }
    public string UtilId { get; set; }
    public string Id
    {
        set
        {
            if (Regex.Match(value, "^[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*$").Success)
            {
                this.id = value;
            }
            else
            {
                UtilId = value;
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return id;
        }
    }
}
```

When you create a property in c#, a private variable is created for that property on compile time. When you try to set the Id property in the code above the Id you pass goes into the value keyword and you can perform your validations on the value keyword and set your property accordingly.
No need to complicate your code with set methods, constructors or deriving classes

or you can even use data annotations which is a more elegant way https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute.aspx#Properties

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class Asset
{
    [RegularExpression("^[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*$")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your post. I tried doing the first option, but getting error "value" cannot be null. Cant use the Dataannotations since its a windows application.

Comment: @Das here is a working fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/J8lk6F please accept the answer if it solves your problem

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion your design should be like below,

You should abstract common items to base class and create specific class inheriting this,

and decide from client(consumer) which instance do you need and construct it

```
public class AssetBase
{
    public string MappingId { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }        
}

public class Asset : AssetBase
{
    public string AssetId { get; set; }
}

public class Util : AssetBase
{
    public string UtilId { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string id = Console.ReadLine();

    if (Regex.Match(id, "^[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*$").Success)
    {
        Asset asset = new Asset();
        asset.AssetId = id;
    }
    else
    {
        Util util = new Util();
        util.UtilId = id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not wrong. It can possibly grow to be a little confusing. Maybe you can make it clearer by moving the bod of `SetStorageId` to the constructor. Perhaps there is no need to complicate with subclassing, relative to other code within the project.